# Check foreign keys

Tags: t-sql

I want to extend my query for delete and update rule, but I just can not figure what column in what systable that is in.

My query so far:

```
select oct.name FKNeve,oft.name TAmit,ofc.name MAmit,ort.name TAmihez,orc.name MAmihez
from sysforeignkeys sfk
inner join sysobjects oct on sfk.constid = oct.id
inner join sysobjects oft on sfk.fkeyid = oft.id
inner join syscolumns ofc on sfk.fkey = ofc.colid and sfk.fkeyid = ofc.id
inner join sysobjects ort on sfk.rkeyid = ort.id
inner join syscolumns orc on sfk.rkey = orc.colid and sfk.rkeyid = orc.id
```

Oh and MSDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [OBJECTPROPERTY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176105.aspx) function (with 'CnstIsDeleteCascade'/'CnstIsUpdateCascade' as the second argument).

Comment: Seems to work. I modified the above lines ...select oct.name FKNeve,oft.name TAmit,ofc.name MAmit,ort.name TAmihez,orc.name MAmihez, objectproperty(sfk.constid,'CnstIsDeleteCascade'), objectproperty(sfk.constid,'CnstIsUpdateCascade')... and it is just what I wanted. Thank you for the help!